# Unable to view cached map service unless logged in as admin in GIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, tilecache

I recently re-created a cache for a map service due to SDE server changes. When the cache finished I was unable to view it unless I manually went to the cache folder and viewed each tile one by one in photoshop.

After a little research I discovered the virtual directory in the cache directory was incorrect. After changing the virtual directory I can now view the cached service in ArcCatalog through my admin login, but cannot view it through the "Use GIS Services". This happens on both the internal and external sites I have.

I've checked security/permissions on everything I can think of, folders, groups, etc. I'm almost certain this is an easy fix, but I'm coming up with nothing. Any help would relieve some stress!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure under your server properties that you have the virtual directory defined that match your websites URL for the arcgiscache path. This way when you talk to the service you can see the proper location.

Also take a look at that virtual directory and make sure the agsUsers group has access to not only the folder; but the virtural directory.

Comment: I removed the ArcGISWebServices user and re-added it to the cache folder. I also removed the same user from the agsusers and agsadmin groups and re-added them. I changed the virtual directory back to what it originally was and mysteriously it worked this morning. Thanks for the help.